# Add a delete tab to the review section

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-delete

The review section is awesome. People at all levels are participating and improving their sites. This I believe is because it's so easy to use. Please add a delete tab to the review system so that 10k/20k users can easily find and deal with posts that have delete votes on them in a similar manner to the close tab.

Answer (score 0):

This already exists in [Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete). You can see all of the questions that have had delete votes cast over the past day, 2 days, 7 days, 14 days, and 30 days. You can sort in order by the *most* delete votes or by the casting of the most *recent* delete vote.

[image]

Since all 10k/20k users with delete vote privileges can access the Tools tab, why do we need this in the Review section as well?

Comment: I cannot speak for the OP, but the current format does not take into account custom sorting (Most commented, Lowest Score First, etc). So if you are on a large site like the trilogy, you cannot drill down to a specific category/tag. And with those items "Most Votes" and "Recent Votes" there is the constant need to expand the tabs (they are collapsed by default)

Comment: @phwd: I have no idea why you'd *delete* a question based on most commented, lowest score, etc. I use this all the time on Stack Overflow, which is the largest site in the network. And yes, you need to expand them. That takes one click. That's no different than having to switch to the "delete" tab you're asking for.

Comment: I don't think (and can nolonger check) that the tools->delete works in a similar fashion to review->close. For review->close when you have reviewed something it is hidden from you whereas (iirc) under tools->delete it's not. This makes it a real pain to work with as there is no obvious way to know if you have already cast a delete vote. Bear in mind also I'm from SF where we don't have many active 10k/20k users so things can hang around for some considerable time before they gather the required votes. Putting it on a tab under /review just puts all the housekeeping functions together.

Comment: This isn't really the same. A review "delete" tab would a) allow you to hide posts you've already looked at, as @Iain mentioned, and b) allow you to work through all votes ever cast. The tools delete tab is limited to 30 days.

Comment: (addendum: limited to 30 days *and* 45 items)

Comment: As lain said, the tools/delete tab really has some important deficiencies.  I will always see posts even after I've reviewed them -- no way to keep track.  And it doesn't tell me which posts I've already voted on, so I click through only to find out I've been here already.  (And further, if I expanded the view past 3, then when I come back it's collapsed again.)  This is a very frustrating interface to use.