# Why aren't questions under the flags tab of the 10k Tools styled with interesting?

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools

In the Review section (other than the suggested edits tab) the questions that appear there are styled to match the tags I'm following (via the CSS .interesting class). Why can't questions under the Flags tab of the Tools section have the same styling applied to immediately draw my attention to the questions I'm best-suited to work on?

Comment: Eh, I'd be more more interested in [moving the delete tab to the review panel](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113397/add-a-delete-tab-to-the-new-review-section) where it *would* have these features.